# Day of the week effect - excluding dummy variables not individually

Tags: stata

I want to test the day of the week effect of stock returns. The stata code I have written works, but looks fairly inefficient.

```
// 1) Monday effect
eststo:reg return day_dummy2 day_dummy3 day_dummy4 day_dummy5
// 2) Tuesday effect
eststo:reg return day_dummy1 day_dummy3 day_dummy4 day_dummy5
// 3) Wednesday effect
eststo:reg return day_dummy1 day_dummy2 day_dummy4 day_dummy5
```

and so on.
Is there a way to write a code with the same function (excluding one day at a time) with e.g. a foreach loop?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit clunky, perhaps, but you could use Stata's macro (see `help extended_fcn`) functions to iteratively exclude one of your listed variables and generate the list of remaining variables.

```
local vars "day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7"
forvalues i = 1/7 {
    local varexclude : word `i' of `vars'
    local varsout`i' : subinstr local vars "`varexclude'" ""
    // insert -estout- command here
}
macro list // to verify the individual `varsout`i'' local macros
```

You can obtain the initial varlist with `ds day*`, which stores the variable list in `r(varlist)`.